# Why is there no user object passed as params for this rails_spec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I have the following rails_spec test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
  fixtures :users, :clients
  include AuthHelper
  before do
    @request.headers["Content-Type"] = 'application/json'
    @request.headers["Accept"] = 'application/json'
  end



 describe '#create' do
    context 'for a user with a valid authorization token' do
      context 'having admin privileges' do
        before do
          init_headers_for_admin
        end

        context 'submitted with a valid set of parameters' do
          it 'should create a new user having the submitted parameters' do
            post :create, params: {
                :name => 'Roland Deschain',
                :email => 'roland@foamfactorybrewing.com',
                :role => 'user',
                :username => 'roland'
            }

            expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)

            user = json

            expect(user).to_not be_nil
            expect(user.name).to eq('Roland Deschain')
            expect(user.email).to eq('roland@foamfactorybrewing.com')
            expect(user.role).to eq('user')
            expect(user.username).to eq('roland')
            expect(user.created_at).to eq(user.updated_at)
          end
        end
```

I also have the following controller definition:

```
def create
# get_required_fields.each { |field|
#   unless params.has_key? field
#     render :json => { :error => 'A ' + field.to_s + ' must be specified in order to create a new User'}, :status => :unprocessable_entity and return
#   end
# }

username = params[:username]
unless User.find_by_username(params[:username]) == nil
  render :json => { :error => I18n.t('error_username_conflict') }, :status => :conflict and return
end

unless User.find_by_email(params[:email]) == nil
  render :json => { :error => I18n.t('error_email_conflict') }, :status => :conflict and return
end
end
```

However, when I run the test, the `params` variable is always an empty hash. If I uncomment the code that detects whether I have the required parameters, it always returns an `UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY`, rather than the `NO_CONTENT` I would expect if a `username`, `name`, and `email` are present. I'm not quite sure why, but I can't seem to get it to pass actual data via the `post` method. I've been looking at this for a while, and trying to debug it, but I can't seem to get it to pass the parameters correctly.

I'm using Rails 5 and rspec_rails 3.8.1.

**EDIT**:

Something is really wrong here, because if I simplify `create` to be:

```
  def create
unless params.has_key?('name') && params.has_key?('username') && params.has_key?('email')
  render :json => {:error => I18n.t('error_must_specify_username_email_and_name')}, :status => :unprocessable_entity and return
end
```

end

And execute the same spec as before (obviously expecting it to return `no_content`, and not `unprocessable_entity`), I end up with the same thing happening - in debug mode, it looks like the `params` variable upon entering this method is:

```
{"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"create", "user"=>{}}
```

So, first off, it's setting the `user` parameter, which isn't *exactly* what I intended, and moreover, it's setting it to an empty hash. I'm not sure what's causing this. I feel like it's something I'm forgetting to do from Rails 5.0, because this pattern seems to work fine in Rails 4.0.

**EDIT 2**:

I modified the test to be:

```
it 'should create a new user record' do
              post :create, params: { user: @user }, as: :json

              expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
              expect(json.name).to eq(@user.name)
              expect(json.email).to eq(@user.email)
              expect(json.username).to eq(@user.username)
              expect(json.role).to eq(@user.role)
            end
```

And modified the `UsersController` class to look like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include AuthHelper

  before_action :validate_api_key_for_auth, only: :login
  before_action :authenticate_as_admin, only: [:create]

  def create
    p user_params
    unless user_params.has_key?('name') && user_params.has_key?('username') && user_params.has_key?('email')
      render :json => {:error => I18n.t('error_must_specify_username_email_and_name')}, :status => :unprocessable_entity and return
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params[:user].permit([:username, :name, :email, :role]).to_h
  end
end
```

It is printing out: `{}` for the `users` hash from `user_params`, but I don't understand why this is the case.

**EDIT 3**:

`authenticate_as_admin` is screwing up the parameters somehow. If I change the definition of `authenticate_as_admin` to `true`, it shows the correct hash and returns `no_content` as expected. The definition of the `authenticate_as_admin` function is below (defined in `ApplicationController`):

```
def authenticate_as_admin
  authenticate_as :admin
end

def authenticate_as(role)
    # First, get the headers for the request
    authorization_header = get_authorization_header

    unless authorization_header
      render :json => {:error => I18n.t('error_must_be_logged_in')}, :status => :forbidden and return false
    end

    auth_token = authorization_header.split[1]

    decoded_token = decode_authorization_header authorization_header
    unless decoded_token
      render :json => {:error => I18n.t('error_invalid_token')}, :status => :forbidden and return false
    end

    payload = decoded_token[0]
    user_id = payload['user_id']
    auth_token_expiration_date = payload['expiration_date']

    @authenticated_user = User.find(user_id) rescue nil

    unless @authenticated_user and @authenticated_user.auth_token == auth_token
      render :json => {:error => I18n.t('error_must_be_logged_in')}, :status => :forbidden and return false
    end

    if auth_token_expiration_date < DateTime.now
      render :json => {:error => I18n.t('error_auth_token_expired')}, :status => :forbidden and return false
    end

    unless @authenticated_user.role_at_least? role
      render :json => {:error => I18n.t('error_insufficient_permission')}, :status => :forbidden and return false
    end

    true
  end
```

I can't seem to see why this would muck up the params, though, especially considering this worked fine in Rails 4.2. Anyone see anything I'm missing?

**EDIT 4**:

I feel like I'm on the right track. It seems as though if the `authenticate_as()` function returns `false`, I get this behavior. If a `before_action` returns `false`, what should be the expected result of a controller action? I expected that the method called in the `before_action` would perform the appropriate `render ...` call, and the `before_action` would silently fail, never calling the function that would have been called. I'm still not quite sure why the function is failing, but I'm trying to understand the behavior that *should* happen. Perhaps authentication checking isn't a great use-case for `before_action`s in Rails 5?

Comment: Do you have permitted params method in the controller? Does it have some `require` part? Look like you need to pass `params: { user: { name: ...} }` in specs

Comment: I tried adding a method called `user_params` that permits all of the params (i.e. with `params.permit!` to the `UsersController`, as well as use that in place of straight parameters, but with no luck.

Comment: I _think_ this is happening because of this: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/13/rails-5-does-not-halt-callback-chain-when-false-is-returned.html What I don't know yet is how to get the `before_action` to perform the `render` of the error message + json, rather than just crashing when `throw :abort` is performed.

Comment: Nix my last comment. This doesn't seem to be the case. I thought this fixed it, but it was just my tired eyes playing tricks on me from another test. Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** Not valid for rails 5

Try this,

```
post :create, {
            :name => 'Roland Deschain',
            :email => 'roland@foamfactorybrewing.com',
            :role => 'user',
            :username => 'roland'
        }
```

when you have the `params: {}` it gets sent as a nested hash, `{ params: {...} }`

**EDIT 1**

Instead of passing `params` to `post :create` try stubbing out `params` call in controller, something like

```
allow(subject).to receive(:params).and_return(params)
```

and inside describe block,

```
let(:params) { ActionController::Parameters.new({ :name => '', :email => '' ... }) }
```

or just a regular hash if you don't need `ActionController::Parameters`

and call the `:create` without any parameters,

```
post :create
```

see if this helps, I am using this pattern in our specs in another project which is on route to rails 5.

Comment: `params: {}` is a valid syntax for new rspec

Comment: Yes, the reason I did it with `params:` is because I'm using rails 5.0, and without that additional notation, I get the following error: `DEPRECATION WARNING: Using positional arguments in functional tests has been deprecated,
in favor of keyword arguments, and will be removed in Rails 5.1.`

Comment: @jwir3 hmm good to know, just moved our main codebase to rails 4.2.10, that will be handy going to rails 5.

Comment: @subash Since you updated the answer with not valid for rails 5, I removed my downvote. Unfortunately, it still doesn't answer the question I was asking. :( I feel like there is something fundamental about how rails 5 treats parameters that I'm not getting.

Comment: I could do what you suggest in your answer edit, but I feel like this is working around the real problem, which is that I don't understand how rails is passing parameters in version 5+. I think I need to solve this, or it's going to bite me in the future.

Comment: What's really odd about this is that it's only happening for the user controller. I have a very similar Clients Controller that seems to be unaffected. It's not using the same authentication methods, though.